# Can anyone say the column name of calendar name in Android 2.2.1?

Tags: android

The column name of calendar name in 2.3+ is:displayName
and in 4.0+ is:calendar_displayName

How ever, these two don't work for 2.2.1. So can any one say me the same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look over this site u can find the solution http://hanscappelle.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-calendar-api-glitches.html

Comment: but among all those column names which one is equivalent to calendar_displayName or displayName.